# How do I populate nibble with 0xF in a character array in C++?

Tags: c++

If I have the following string:

```
std::string mcc_mnc = "272005"
```

And I do the following:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
byte ecgi[3];

//byte 1
ecgi[0] = byte(mcc_mnc[0] - '0');
ecgi[0] = ecgi[0] | byte((mcc_mnc[1] - '0') << 4);

//byte 2
ecgi[1] = byte(mcc_mnc[2] - '0');
ecgi[1] = ecgi[1] | byte((mcc_mnc[5] - '0') << 4);

//byte 3
ecgi[2] = byte(mcc_mnc[3] - '0');
ecgi[2] = ecgi[2] | byte((mcc_mnc[4] - '0') << 4);
```

Byte 1 `ecgi[0]` should now contain:

```
01110010 (0x72)
```

Byte 2 `ecgi[1]` should now contain:

```
01010010 (0x52)
```

Byte 3 `ecgi[2]` should now contain:

```
00000000 (0x00)
```

I would like to change the above so that Byte 3 `ecgi[2]` looks like this:

```
00001111 (0x0F)
```

Comment: Why should it contain 0x0F ?
If the purpose is to translate hex characters into binary, then what it currently does looks correct? Perhaps you mean how to handle the case 'a' ... 'f' ?

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough. Right now `ecgi[2] = 0x0F;` would be a correct answer, but very likely not the solution to your actual problem. Try to describe your algorithm a bit more general, so we understand what you're trying to do and why you expect that value instead of `0`.

Comment: the values you show for byte 3 don't make any sense. `0000FFFF` is not `0x0F` just because you wrote them beside each other, so what are you trying to say?

Comment: @Useless I think OP meant `00001111`, but of course it's good to ask for clarification.

Comment: @E van Putten: Go to http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/129100_129199/129171/11.03.00_60/ts_129171v110300p.pdf, this will download a pdf, see page 32, section 7.4.27 PLMN Identity: `1111 used as filler digit,
two digits per octet`

Comment: @Max Vollmer:: Apologies my mistake, it should have been 00001111, not 0000FFFF. I have corrected the question.

Comment: Please add essential information to your question, not in comments. Write down the important bits necessary to understand the requirements and then provide the link to that PDF as a source. Make sure that it's possible to fully understand the requirements without that PDF, as links can go dead in the future and we want questions to remain useful and understandable in the future. Thanks!

Comment: So if I understand correctly you have some sort of string with digits.
And it should be translated in either 3 nibbles + "filler" nibble (1111) + 2 digits MNC, or 3 nibbles + 3 nibbles MNC (no filler this time).
How to distinguish between the two?
I mean just setting 4 bits on is simply OR'ing a value with 0xF0 (for the high nibble) or 0x0F for the low nibble

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply setting the lower nibble to all 1's would be:

```
ecgi[2] |= 0xf;
```

Or in some (modern) compilers that support binary literals:

```
ecgi[2] |= 0b1111;
```

This performs a bitwise OR operation, effectively setting all the bits from the right hand side.